# Create another admin user in Influx 2.0

Tags: console, user-management, influxdb-2

How is it possible to create another admin user in Influx 2.0? Lower versions provide the feature directly on creating with an additional "WITH ALL PRIVILEGES". But for Influx 2.0, I cannot find any clue to add a 2nd or even 3rd admin.

I can create a bunch of non-admin users, but they are, e.g., not able to create/edit tasks and stuff.